# How to extract specific text from html using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some text from an HTML (to be more specifically.It is Mdx, a kind of #dictionary file)using BeautifulSoup function in python- it runs well but I am not getting what I need. # My code is of the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

html = '''
abandon <link href="LM5style_vanilla.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_switch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_show.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><script src="LM5Switch.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><span class="lm5ppbody"><div class="entry_content"><h1 class="pagetitle" pagetype="0">abandon</h1><div class="dictionary"><div class="wordfams"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold foldsign_fold"><span class="asset_intro">Word family</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span><span class="LDOCE_word_family" style="display:none;"> <span class="pos">noun</span> <span class="w" title="abandonment">abandonment</span> <span class="pos">adjective</span> <a class="crossRef w" href="bword://abandoned" title="abandoned">abandoned</a> <span class="pos">verb</span> <span class="w" title="abandon">abandon</span> </span></div><!-- End of DIV wordfams--><span class="dictentry"><span class="dictionary_intro span"><span class="lm5ppMenu"><span id="lm5ppMenu_logo"> </span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title"><span class="en_title">Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文当代英语 5++</span></span></span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title mini"><span class="en_title">LDOCE 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文 5++</span></span></span></span></span><span class="dictlink"><a name="abandon__entry_0__a"></a><span class="ldoceEntry Entry" id="abandon__entry_0"><span class="frequent Head"><span class="HWD">a<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>ban<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>don</span><span class="HOMNUM">1</span><a class="PronCodes" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3"><span class="neutral span"> /</span><span class="PRON">əˈbændən</span><span class="neutral span">/</span></a> <span class="tooltip LEVEL" title="Core vocabulary: Medium-frequency"> ●●○</span> <span class="FREQ" title="Top 3000 written words">W3</span> <span class="AC" title="Academic Word list">AWL</span><span class="lm5pp_POS"> verb</span><span class="GRAM"><span class="neutral span"> [</span>transitive<span class="neutral span">]</span></span><a class="speaker brefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" href="sound://media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" title="Play British pronunciation of abandon"> </a><a class="speaker amefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" title="Play American pronunciation of abandon"> </a></span><a name="abandon__1__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__1"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">1</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A RELATIONSHIP</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to leave someone, especially someone you are <a class="defRef" href="bword://responsible" title="responsible">responsible</a> for</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 抛弃，遗弃〔某人〕</span></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span"> → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963493.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">How could she abandon her own child?<span class="cn_txt"> 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__2__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__2"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">2</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A PLACE</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to go away from a place, <a class="defRef" href="bword://vehicle" title="vehicle">vehicle</a> etc permanently, especially because the situation makes it <a class="defRef" href="bword://impossible" title="impossible">impossible</a> for you to stay</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 离弃，逃离〔某地方、交通工具等〕</span></span><span class="SYN"> <span class="synopp span">SYN</span><a href="bword://leave"> leave</a></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span">, → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963497.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way.<span class="cn_txt"> 我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963498.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city.<span class="cn_txt"> 因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__3__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__3"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">3</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">STOP DOING something</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to stop doing something because there are too many problems and it is impossible to continue</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 放弃，中止</span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963502.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">The game had to be abandoned due to bad weather.<span class="cn_txt"> 由于天气不好，比赛不得不中止。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001732862.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">They <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA">attempt</span> to recapture the castle.<span class="cn_txt"> 他们放弃了夺回城堡的努力。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001776706.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Because of the fog they <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA"<span>someone, </span><span>you </span></div></div>\n</span>\n
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
context = soup.find_all(class_="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children")
print(context)

#this is what it runs:[<span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">How could she abandon her own child?<span class="cn_txt"> 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？</span></span>, <span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way.<span class="cn_txt"> 我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。</span></span>, <span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city.<span class="cn_txt"> 因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。</span></span>,
```

What i need are all of the english and Chinese samples like this:

```
How could she abandon her own child?
她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？
```

I had tried several days. Please help me. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please format the code and data. Select it and type `ctrl-k`.[Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll formate it.

Comment: Have have you done to try to debug this? Have you narrowed down the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your problem right. If you want to extract english phrases and chinese counterparts, you can use this example (I don't know any chinese, so I cannot verify if this is right output):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
abandon <link href="LM5style_vanilla.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_switch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_show.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><script src="LM5Switch.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><span class="lm5ppbody"><div class="entry_content"><h1 class="pagetitle" pagetype="0">abandon</h1><div class="dictionary"><div class="wordfams"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold foldsign_fold"><span class="asset_intro">Word family</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span><span class="LDOCE_word_family" style="display:none;"> <span class="pos">noun</span> <span class="w" title="abandonment">abandonment</span> <span class="pos">adjective</span> <a class="crossRef w" href="bword://abandoned" title="abandoned">abandoned</a> <span class="pos">verb</span> <span class="w" title="abandon">abandon</span> </span></div><!-- End of DIV wordfams--><span class="dictentry"><span class="dictionary_intro span"><span class="lm5ppMenu"><span id="lm5ppMenu_logo"> </span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title"><span class="en_title">Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文当代英语 5++</span></span></span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title mini"><span class="en_title">LDOCE 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文 5++</span></span></span></span></span><span class="dictlink"><a name="abandon__entry_0__a"></a><span class="ldoceEntry Entry" id="abandon__entry_0"><span class="frequent Head"><span class="HWD">a<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>ban<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>don</span><span class="HOMNUM">1</span><a class="PronCodes" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3"><span class="neutral span"> /</span><span class="PRON">əˈbændən</span><span class="neutral span">/</span></a> <span class="tooltip LEVEL" title="Core vocabulary: Medium-frequency"> ●●○</span> <span class="FREQ" title="Top 3000 written words">W3</span> <span class="AC" title="Academic Word list">AWL</span><span class="lm5pp_POS"> verb</span><span class="GRAM"><span class="neutral span"> [</span>transitive<span class="neutral span">]</span></span><a class="speaker brefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" href="sound://media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" title="Play British pronunciation of abandon"> </a><a class="speaker amefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" title="Play American pronunciation of abandon"> </a></span><a name="abandon__1__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__1"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">1</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A RELATIONSHIP</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to leave someone, especially someone you are <a class="defRef" href="bword://responsible" title="responsible">responsible</a> for</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 抛弃，遗弃〔某人〕</span></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span"> → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963493.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">How could she abandon her own child?<span class="cn_txt"> 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__2__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__2"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">2</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A PLACE</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to go away from a place, <a class="defRef" href="bword://vehicle" title="vehicle">vehicle</a> etc permanently, especially because the situation makes it <a class="defRef" href="bword://impossible" title="impossible">impossible</a> for you to stay</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 离弃，逃离〔某地方、交通工具等〕</span></span><span class="SYN"> <span class="synopp span">SYN</span><a href="bword://leave"> leave</a></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span">, → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963497.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way.<span class="cn_txt"> 我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963498.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city.<span class="cn_txt"> 因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__3__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__3"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">3</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">STOP DOING something</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to stop doing something because there are too many problems and it is impossible to continue</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 放弃，中止</span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963502.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">The game had to be abandoned due to bad weather.<span class="cn_txt"> 由于天气不好，比赛不得不中止。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001732862.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">They <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA">attempt</span> to recapture the castle.<span class="cn_txt"> 他们放弃了夺回城堡的努力。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001776706.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Because of the fog they <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA"<span>someone, </span><span>you </span></div></div>\n</span>\n
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print('{:^80} {:^80}'.format('English', 'Chinese'))
print('-' * 160)
for english in soup.select('.english:has(.cn_txt)'):
    cn_txt = english.select_one('.cn_txt').get_text(strip=True)
    english.select_one('.cn_txt').extract()
    eng_txt = english.get_text(separator=' ', strip=True)

    print('{:<80} {:<80}'.format(eng_txt, cn_txt))
```

Prints:

```
                                    English                                                                          Chinese                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
How could she abandon her own child?                                             她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？                                                                   
We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way.                          我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。                                                                
Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city.          因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。                                                          
The game had to be abandoned due to bad weather.                                 由于天气不好，比赛不得不中止。                                                                 
They abandoned their attempt to recapture the castle.                            他们放弃了夺回城堡的努力。
```

Comment: It's perfect!!! You are a lifesaver.
I don't 100% understand it yet, but it works!

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question.
It worked when the file is 4 M , but It didn't while the file up to 600 M. Is there a limited to print() in python?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
longmanFile = open('c:\\longman3.txt', 'r',encoding= 'utf-8')
longmanContent = longmanFile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(longmanContent, 'lxml')

#soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

Comment: @DevinLiu 600MB is big file...BeauttifulSoup will take lot of time to process it. Maybe split the file to lesser chunks or use another approach.

Comment: ok, I got it . I'll spit it to small chunks and try again. 
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add a loop like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

html = '''
    abandon <link href="LM5style_vanilla.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_switch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="LM5style_show.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><script src="LM5Switch.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script><span class="lm5ppbody"><div class="entry_content"><h1 class="pagetitle" pagetype="0">abandon</h1><div class="dictionary"><div class="wordfams"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold foldsign_fold"><span class="asset_intro">Word family</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span><span class="LDOCE_word_family" style="display:none;"> <span class="pos">noun</span> <span class="w" title="abandonment">abandonment</span> <span class="pos">adjective</span> <a class="crossRef w" href="bword://abandoned" title="abandoned">abandoned</a> <span class="pos">verb</span> <span class="w" title="abandon">abandon</span> </span></div><!-- End of DIV wordfams--><span class="dictentry"><span class="dictionary_intro span"><span class="lm5ppMenu"><span id="lm5ppMenu_logo"> </span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title"><span class="en_title">Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文当代英语 5++</span></span></span><span class="lm5ppMenu_title mini"><span class="en_title">LDOCE 5++</span><span class="cn_title"><span class="cn_txt_menu">朗文 5++</span></span></span></span></span><span class="dictlink"><a name="abandon__entry_0__a"></a><span class="ldoceEntry Entry" id="abandon__entry_0"><span class="frequent Head"><span class="HWD">a<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>ban<span class="HYP"><span class="HYP">·</span></span>don</span><span class="HOMNUM">1</span><a class="PronCodes" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3"><span class="neutral span"> /</span><span class="PRON">əˈbændən</span><span class="neutral span">/</span></a> <span class="tooltip LEVEL" title="Core vocabulary: Medium-frequency"> ●●○</span> <span class="FREQ" title="Top 3000 written words">W3</span> <span class="AC" title="Academic Word list">AWL</span><span class="lm5pp_POS"> verb</span><span class="GRAM"><span class="neutral span"> [</span>transitive<span class="neutral span">]</span></span><a class="speaker brefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" href="sound://media/english/breProns/abandon_v0205.mp3" title="Play British pronunciation of abandon"> </a><a class="speaker amefile fa fa-volume-up" data-src-mp3="/media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" href="sound://media/english/ameProns/abandon1.mp3" title="Play American pronunciation of abandon"> </a></span><a name="abandon__1__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__1"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">1</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A RELATIONSHIP</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to leave someone, especially someone you are <a class="defRef" href="bword://responsible" title="responsible">responsible</a> for</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 抛弃，遗弃〔某人〕</span></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span"> → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963493.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">How could she abandon her own child?<span class="cn_txt"> 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__2__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__2"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">2</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">LEAVE A PLACE</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to go away from a place, <a class="defRef" href="bword://vehicle" title="vehicle">vehicle</a> etc permanently, especially because the situation makes it <a class="defRef" href="bword://impossible" title="impossible">impossible</a> for you to stay</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 离弃，逃离〔某地方、交通工具等〕</span></span><span class="SYN"> <span class="synopp span">SYN</span><a href="bword://leave"> leave</a></span><span class="RELATEDWD"><span class="neutral span">, → </span><a href="bword://abandoned"> abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963497.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way.<span class="cn_txt"> 我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963498.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city.<span class="cn_txt"> 因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。</span></span></span></span><a name="abandon__3__a"></a><span class="newline Sense" id="abandon__3"><span class="LDOCE5pp_sensefold"><span class="sensenum span">3</span><span class="foldsign"><span class="foldblank"> </span><span class="foldsignbar1"></span><span class="foldsignbar2"></span></span></span> <span class="ACTIV">STOP DOING something</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings">to stop doing something because there are too many problems and it is impossible to continue</span><span class="DEF LDOCE_switch_lang switch_siblings"> <span class="cn_txt"> 放弃，中止</span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963502.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">The game had to be abandoned due to bad weather.<span class="cn_txt"> 由于天气不好，比赛不得不中止。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001732862.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">They <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA">attempt</span> to recapture the castle.<span class="cn_txt"> 他们放弃了夺回城堡的努力。</span></span></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-001776706.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">Because of the fog they <span class="COLLOINEXA">abandoned</span> their <span class="COLLOINEXA"<span>someone, </span><span>you </span></div></div>\n</span>\n
    '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
context = soup.find_all(class_="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children")
#print(context)
for x in context:
  print(x.text)
```

Result :

```
How could she abandon her own child? 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？
We had to abandon the car and walk the rest of the way. 我们只好弃车，步行走完剩下的路。
Fearing further attacks, most of the population had abandoned the city. 因为害怕还要受到袭击，大多数市民已逃离该市。
The game had to be abandoned due to bad weather. 由于天气不好，比赛不得不中止。
They abandoned their attempt to recapture the castle. 他们放弃了夺回城堡的努力。
Because of the fog they abandoned their someone, you
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It works very well.
You guys save my day!

Comment: Thank you again! I'd like to know is it possible to extract the（1） word,（2） English example,（3）Chinese,（3）mp3 link together at the same time?

Comment: well, what I'd like to do is to extract following (each line contain a word and explain):
1,word; 2,mp3link; 3,English example;4,Chinese exampl;
abandon <link .......abandoned</a></span><span class="EXAMPLE"><a class="speaker exafile fa fa-volume-up" href="sound://media/english/exaProns/p008-000963493.mp3" title="Play Example"> </a><span class="english LDOCE_switch_lang switch_children">How could she abandon her own child?<span class="cn_txt"> 她怎么能抛弃自己的孩子呢？</span></span></span>

Thank you!